# Intersection of subgroups is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, coprime

We all know that if two subgroups $A \le G$ and $B \le G$ have coprime order $\gcd(|A|, |B|)=1$, then their intersection is trivial: $A \cap B=\{e\}$.

Does the converse of this statement remains true? I mean, is it true that *if an intersection of two subgroups is trivial $A \cap B = \{e\}$, then their orders are coprime $\gcd(|A|, |B|)=1$?*

I think that dihedral group $D_3$ may be a good counterexample here: subgroups of rotations and reflections have equal order, but do they intersect only by $\{e\}$? (seems wrong actually:))

Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you mean their orders (rather than their coprimes) are coprime?  Consider the [Klein four-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group), which is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order four

Comment: yes, I mean that thanks

Comment: So, you mean that in dihedral group of order 4 there are two subgroups with non-coprime order which has trivial intersection?

Comment: Take the ambient group to be $G\times G$ for any $G$; the subgroup $G \times \{e\}$ has the same order as $\{e\} \times G$, but their intersection is the identity!

Comment: @thorimur That's a better one, thanks!

Comment: my example was $G\times G$ where $G=\mathbb Z_2$; the three non-identity elements generate cyclic groups of order $2$, and the intersection of any two of them is $\{e\}$

Comment: Also note that any two distinct subgroups of prime order $p$ necessarily have trivial intersection.